# yesod-core fails to build on Mavericks

Tags: macos, haskell, installation, yesod

I have a Homebrew-installed Haskell platform version 2013.2.0.0 with GHC 7.6.3 and an up-to-date cabal install.  I try to install yesod-core - it grabs version 1.2.6.4, and I get this compilation error:

```
[11 of 20] Compiling Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ( Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-74f8d9fc/build/Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.o )

Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:519:81:
    Could not deduce (aeson-0.7.0.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.ToJSON
                        Network.HTTP.Types.Method.Method)
      arising from a use of `.='
    from the context (Yesod site)
      bound by the type signature for
                 defaultErrorHandler :: Yesod site =>
                                        ErrorResponse -> HandlerT site IO TypedContent
      at Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:439:24-83
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (aeson-0.7.0.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.ToJSON
         Network.HTTP.Types.Method.Method)
    In the expression: "method" .= m
    In the first argument of `object', namely
      `["message" .= ("Bad method" :: Text), "method" .= m]'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `object ["message" .= ("Bad method" :: Text), "method" .= m]'
```

... which looks like an actual bug in the Yesod code. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Note that it's highly recommended to use the yesod-platform to install versions of dependencies which are known to work correctly together.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman:  I did.  When it failed, I tracked the specific failure down to yesod-core.

Comment: But there's no version of yesod-platform which uses aeson-0.7.0.0. Why was it trying to build yesod-core against that version of aeson?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman OK, I tried starting over on a different Mac. I successfully installed yesod-platform 1.2.5.3 with aeson-0.6.2.1. I had no 'yesod' executable, so I installed yesod-bin as well. That worked fine. But when I created a cabal sandbox for a new yesod app and ran a plain `cabal install` in it, it installed aeson-0.7.0.0.  Then `yesod test` complained that `yesod-test` and `hspec` weren't installed, and when I tried to install them it recompiled yesod-core with the 0.7 aeson and boom. So I had to do `cabal install aeson-0.6.2.1 yesod-test`.

Comment: The problem was that you did `cabal install yesod` in the sandbox instead of `cabal install yesod-platform`.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman: no, I didn't.  I did `yesod init` followed by `cabal sandbox init` and `cabal install` - the latter with no arguments at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a build dependency issue in `yesod-core`, The developers on the irc channel are aware of the issue.  To work around this trying installing `yesod-core` with this command

```
cabal install aeson-0.6.2.1 yesod-core
```

This will force the use of the previous version of `aeson` which works on my system in a fresh `cabal sandbox`.